# While Re Connecting signalR, message is not delivered. Any example to reconnect user in the same group?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

While Re Connecting signalR, message is not delivered. Any example to reconnect user in the same group ?

specifically for ASP.NET core 5.0

Comment: You can check the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups)

Comment: issue already resolved... but thanks for helping